# Is this topology separable, first countable, second countable?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, second-countable, first-countable

Consider a set $E$ with some point $p \in E$ and the topology:
$T = \left \{ \emptyset \right \}\cup \left \{ C \subset E: p \in E \right \}$.
Is this topology, separable, first countable or second countable?

I feel like it depends on the size of $E$, because $|P(E)| = 2^{|E|}$ but I'm struggling to figure out what a base for this topology would look like which makes it difficult to answer the questions about countability. Any solutions or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology

Comment: In the definition of $T$, did you mean $\{C\subseteq E:p\in\color{red}C\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is knwon as the
[particular point tpology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology). You can find all you need in the wikipedia page. By the way $p$ is always dense so $T$ is always separable, for any $x$ the set $\{x,p\}$ is a local basis at $x$, so $T$ is first countable. As you mention, the second countability depends on the cardinality of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm still not sure about countability but the set $\left \{ p \right \}$ is in fact dense because the only closed set containing $p$ is $E$ itself meaning that the closure $\bar{\left \{ p \right \}}$ is the intersection of only one set $E$ meaning that the set is dense and because the set is countable (finite in fact), the space is separable.

Comment: This is correct.